# Uncommenting fragment of XML with Xml Document in C#

Tags: c#, regex, xml, parsing, dom

What is the easiest way of uncommenting the body of some node in XML? The elements have unique name, the structure of the documents look as follows:

somefile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<name1>
  <irrelevant1>
    <irrelevant2>
    <!--
      <irrelevant3 />
    -->
    </irrelevant2>
  </irrelevant1>
  <name2>
    <name3>
    <!--
      <name4 field="The" />
      <name4 field="Owls" />
      <name4 field="Are />
      <name4 field="Not" />
      <name4 field="What" />
      <name4 field="They" />
      <name4 field="Seem />
    -->
    </name3>
  </name2>
</name1>
```

The goal should look like this, with comments removed:

uncommented.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<name1>
  <irrelevant1>
    <irrelevant2>
    <!--
      <irrelevant3 />
    -->
    </irrelevant2>
  </irrelevant1>
  <name2>
    <name3>
      <name4 field="The" />
      <name4 field="Owls" />
      <name4 field="Are />
      <name4 field="Not" />
      <name4 field="What" />
      <name4 field="They" />
      <name4 field="Seem />
    </name3>
  </name2>
</name1>
```

My approach to parsing:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(@"C:\somefile.xml");

XmlNodeList nl = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("name2");

XmlNode xn = nl[0];
string xn_content = xn.InnerXml;

xn_content = Regex.Replace(xn_content, "<!--|-->", String.Empty);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xn_content);
XmlNode newNode = doc.DocumentElement;

// this import doesn't really help
xdoc.ImportNode(newNode, true);
xn.RemoveAll();
xn.AppendChild(newNode);

xdoc.Save(@"C:\uncommented.xml");
```

Results with the ArgumentException:

> {"The node to be inserted is from a different document context."}

Comment: Are you open to using Linq to XML (XDocument)?

Comment: Why **irrelevant3** is not uncommnented. What is the rule to use for `irrelevant2` and to `name3`. Why only `name3`s childs are uncommented? How can we differentiate them programmaticallt?

Comment: You are missing closing quotes for `<name4 field="Are />`.  It should be `<name4 field="Are" />`.  And also for `<name4 field="Seem />`.

Comment: @EZI : I use xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("name2") to work only on the portion of the content, this way my regex works against the desired fragment

Comment: @Christopher Painter: Yes, if it simplifies the parsing. But I got the satisfying answer from dbc already.

Comment: @sirVir in Linq you just get the descendant nodes and iterate through them checking to see if they are an XComment.  Then you call the ReplaceWith() method passing it the XComment.Value property.  Your XComment is now an XElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you call [`XmlDocument.ImportNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but do not use the returned node.  You need to do `newNode = xDoc.ImportNode(newNode, true);`.

However, a cleaner way to do this would be to avoid the `Regex` parsing entirely.  Instead, descend the `XmlNode` hierarchy, pick out the [`XmlComment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlcomment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) nodes you wish to uncomment, load their [`InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlcharacterdata.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) into an [`XmlDocumentFragment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocumentfragment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then add its newly created children to the parent node of the comment:

```
public static class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static XmlDocument Document(this XmlNode node)
    {
        for (; node != null; node = node.ParentNode)
        {
            var doc = node as XmlDocument;
            if (doc != null)
                return doc;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XmlNode> AncestorsAndSelf(this XmlNode node)
    {
        for (; node != null; node = node.ParentNode)
            yield return node;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XmlNode> DescendantsAndSelf(this XmlNode root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            yield break;
        yield return root;
        foreach (var child in root.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>())
            foreach (var subChild in child.DescendantsAndSelf())
                yield return subChild;
    }

    public static void UncommentXmlNodes(IEnumerable<XmlComment> comments)
    {
        foreach (var comment in comments.ToList())
            UncommentXmlNode(comment);
    }

    public static void UncommentXmlNode(XmlComment comment)
    {
        if (comment == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        var doc = comment.Document();
        if (doc == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var parent = comment.ParentNode;
        var innerText = comment.InnerText;
        XmlDocumentFragment docFrag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
        //Set the contents of the document fragment.
        docFrag.InnerXml = innerText;
        XmlNode insertAfter = comment;
        foreach (var child in docFrag.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().ToList())
        {
            insertAfter = parent.InsertAfter(child, insertAfter);
        }
        parent.RemoveChild(comment);
    }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
        <name1>
          <irrelevant1>
            <irrelevant2>
            <!--
              <irrelevant3 />
            -->
            </irrelevant2>
          </irrelevant1>
          <name2>
            <name3>
            <!--
              <name4 field=""The"" />
              <name4 field=""Owls"" />
              <name4 field=""Are"" />
              <name4 field=""Not"" />
              <name4 field=""What"" />
              <name4 field=""They"" />
              <name4 field=""Seem"" />
            -->
            </name3>
          </name2>
        </name1>
        ";
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
        Debug.WriteLine(xmlDoc.ToXml());

        XmlNodeExtensions.UncommentXmlNodes(xmlDoc.DocumentElement.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<XmlComment>().Where(c => c.ParentNode.Name == "name3"));

        Debug.WriteLine(xmlDoc.ToXml());
```

Note that your commented XML is invalid.  `<name4 field="Are />` should be `<name4 field="Are"/>` and `<name4 field="Seem />` should be `<name4 field="Seem"/>`.  I fixed that for you in the test case since I assume it's a typo.